# The result of the following code is just the input data as a table

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, market-basket-analysis

The following code just displays the input values, instead of support and confidence. Why?

```
DECLARE @rscript NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @rscript = N'
  library(arules)
  library(arulesViz)
  OutputDataSet <- data.frame(
  age   = as.factor(c(6, 6, 8, 8, NA, 9, 16)),
  grade = as.factor(c("A", "C", "C", "C", "F", NA, "C")),
  pass  = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)) 
rules <- apriori(OutputDataSet,parameter=list(supp= 0.001,conf = 0.8))
print(rules)';
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'R',
@script = @rscript,
 @input_data_1 = N'
```